# Export Specific updates from WSUS

Tags: wsus, wsus-offline

My team manages multiple environments that are offline.  We currently export our WSUS updates from a server that is used by multiple groups and therefore has a lot more updates than what we need or would like to have to copy.

Is there anyway possible to only export certain updates from WSUS.  For instance just Server 2012R2 and Windows 7?

Comment: You can get a list of updates but what information do you need for the export?

Comment: I need to export the critical and security updates for the OS's that are in our area's.  Currently the WSUS content folder is roughly 70Gb which encompasses multiple OS versions, Office products, SQL etc.  Most of which does not apply to us.  Just trying to find a way to cut back on all the unnecessary data being transferred and imported into our WSUS servers.

Comment: Sorry I mean't, do you need the filepath, the kb, the description. How are you exporting them? You can use powershell for example https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/01/18/approve-or-decline-wsus-updates-by-using-powershell/

Comment: I am new to this group and this is one of my projects to make this process more effective.  Currently they are using WSUSutil to export the metadata from the WSUS server and copying the entire wsus content folder Then again WSUSutil to import.  As mentioned when the metadata is exported it comes with everything as does the wsus content folder.  I was hoping there was a way when exporting to only export metadata based on certain criteria and then only pull that content from the wsus content folder.  The powershell link you provided looks like a good start for listing the updates, now to export.

Comment: Ah I see - Ok you might be able to do what you want with powershell but you might be reinventing the wheel in this case. Also depending on your wsus version there are also some native powershell cmdlets which might make things easier https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/05/27/use-the-updateservices-module-to-manage-wsus/

Comment: I'm definitely not trying to reinvent the wheel.  I just have not been able to find anything for powershell or cmd that keep allows you to filter through the updates when exporting the metadata.  I will definitely look into the powershell links you have provided and see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: jdycus002 - Were you ever able to figure this out? Is it possible to export specific updates instead of all of them?

Comment: @mhunt359 - For my scenario I was eventually able to accomplish what I needed. I had to have a wsus server that I controlled the sync content from Microsoft to keep the metadata output small and them used Powershell to handle approvals and export of approvals